# "ssh-add ~/.ssh" only loads one identity when it should load all of them

Tags: ssh

```
me@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  two_rsa  two_rsa.pub
me@ubuntu: ssh-add ~/.ssh
me@ubuntu: ssh-add -l 
2048 7f:76:9d:b4:ae:f0:72:dd:36:c4:25:02:e0:b5:12:a6 /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Why isn't `two_rsa` being loaded? Also, should a production server only have one id loaded at any one time? Is that what's causing this behaviour?

Comment: Just go to your .ssh directory, click open a private key file, import  it and check the box "Automatically unlock the key when I am logged in".

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell ssh-add to add the file. It won't recursively add all your files under `~/.ssh`. The correct method is using:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/two_rsa
```

Comment: Cool. Can I recursively add, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Starkers ssh-add can't recursively add files. Is just a bad idea and that's why it didn't get implemented.